# C# UWP show x number of ListView in ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, listview, uwp

So I am pretty unsure how to work this picture out.
[image]
I think they have a ScrollView here and within that ScrollView different ListViews.

How can I show an unknown number of ListViews organized like that?

I am even stuck on the Part how to show only 9 pictures and one of them being large. 
All I got is:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="3" 
              Grid.RowSpan="1"
              Grid.Column="0"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
                            <GridView Background="#fafafa"
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMovie,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FilteredMoviesList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                      IsSwipeEnabled="True">
                                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid Margin="3"
                                              Width="120" 
                                              Height="120">

                                            <Grid>
                                                <Rectangle Opacity="1" 
                                                           Fill="White"
                                                           Height="120"
                                                           Width="120"/>
                                                <Image Source="{Binding ImgSource}" 
                                                       Width="120"
                                                       Height="190"
                                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                <Border BorderBrush="#161616" 
                                                        Background="#16161601" 
                                                        Opacity="0.9"
                                                        BorderThickness="0.1">
                                                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                            Background="#000000">
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                                               Foreground="#f2f2f2"
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                               FontWeight="Bold"
                                               TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                               Margin="2"
                                               MaxWidth="120"
                                               FontSize="13"/>
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateOfShot}"
                                               Foreground="#f2f2f2"
                                               FontWeight="SemiBold"
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                               FontSize="10"
                                               Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </Border>
                                                <Rectangle Width="120"
                                           Height="120"
                                           Fill="#000000"
                                           Opacity="0.1"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                            </GridView>

                        </ScrollViewer>
```

Which shows all Items

[image]

Comment: Hey Daniel do you happen to have the full source code to this you made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three steps to achieve this layout

### Step 1:

Use [Hub Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/hub) to do it.

Here is a sample image. Source: [Hub control/pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/hub)

[image]

#### Syntax

```
<Hub>
    <HubSection>
        <DataTemplate>

        </DataTemplate>
    </HubSection>
</Hub>
```

### Step 2:

To show one large and 8 small image

Show the large image in `<Image>` and remaining 8 in a `GridView` in a StackPanel or [VariableSizedWrapGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.VariableSizedWrapGrid)

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image/>
        <GridView/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

### Step 3:

To restrict the number of Item in `GridView` is to change the `ItemsSource`. For that, you can use converters.

In XAML

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>

<GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ItemsSourceCollection, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"/>
```

In Code Behind

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return (value as ObservableCollection<ItemSource>).Take(8);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

For more info: [Hub control/pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/hub), [Hub Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Hub), [HubSection Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.HubSection)

For sample project: [XamlUIBasics](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlUIBasics)

Comment: And everything can be so easy. ty

Comment: ty again! nice answer!